# Trouble sourcing YAML syntax highlighting

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, filetype-yaml

I'm doing some Ansible work (on RHEL 8), so I want the YAML configs for vim.  I have a yaml.vim file containing the syntax/etc, and a ~/.vimrc file:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.yaml,*.yml so ~/.vim/yaml.vim
autocmd FileType yaml,yml set ai ts=2 sw=2 et number
```

While logged in as user ansible, that worked just peachy with *.yml files.  But then I copied the same files to the same places under ~ (root), and when I was root (via su or su -), vim was clueless about yaml.

I tried changing the ~/.vim/yaml.vim in .vimrc to ~root/.vim/yaml.vim -- no joy.

With some digging I discovered that vi doesn't read .vimrc when you're root but vim does!!??  But vim didn't work either.

Out of exasperation I tried rebooting my Linux server.  Now it doesn't work for user ansible either!!??

I tried :source ~/.vimrc and it kinda worked.  That picked up the .vimrc settings but not the syntax-highlight stuff in yaml.vim, even if I did a :e! to force it to re-read the file and see the file suffix.  But that only worked for root!?  And only a few times.  Now it doesn't work.  :source ~/.vim/yaml.vim doesn't do anything either.

I looked at `vim -V` and `:scriptnames` and both indicate .vimrc and yaml.vim are being sourced.  E.g. :scriptnames output:

```
  1: ~/.vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 14: ~/.vim/yaml.vim
```

So why am I not picking up the FileType settings (`set ai ts=2 sw=2 et number`) from .vimrc (item 1) or the YAML syntax highlighting from yaml.vim (item 14)?  Especially since this worked, for non-root, until I rebooted !?

Comment: Do you have file types enabled with `filetype on` (or better `filetype plugin indent on`) on your vimrc? When you open a YAML file, if you use `:set ft?` does it tell you `filetype=yaml`? If it doesn't, then that should explain why your `autocmd FileType` is not working.

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  :set ft says "filetype=".  This is true for .yml and .yaml.  I added `filetype on` to my .vimrc and it picked up the `ai ts=2` &etc from the autocmd FileType.  Now :set ft says "filetype=yaml".

I'm 99.9% sure I never had `filetype on` in there before, so I don't know why it worked before, and then it didn't.  

Still have a problem with the yaml.vim file.  I assume it's a valid file because it worked before, but I did make a few changes there so it's possible I broke something.  Is there an authoritative YAML syntax file?

Comment: Yes, there's an authoritative YAML syntax file, and now with `filetype on` I'd expect you'll be sourcing it. Check your `:scriptnames`, I'm betting you'll see `/usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/yaml.vim` there (and also `/usr/share/vim/vim80/indent.yaml.vim`). Can you confirm that? In any case, I'll probably write an answer for you shortly.

Comment: BTW I strongly recommend not modifying `ts` from 8. Instead, if you want a different level of indentation when you use a Tab in insert mode, set `sts` (softtabstop) instead. You can set it to 2 in this case. It's quite possible that the default YAML plugin will do that already though, so you might not need to manually change that.

Comment: PS if you want to deal with syntax, best to put it in `~/.vim/syntax/yaml.vim`. Also use `setlocal`

Comment: No, the :scriptnames output is in the original post -- the only reference to yaml.vim is the one under ~/.vim.

Here are all instances of yaml.vim on my RHEL8 system:

`/root/.vim/yaml.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/yaml.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim80/indent/yaml.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/yaml.vim
/home/ansible/.vim/yaml.vim`

What's the right way to use the files under /usr/share/vim?  Should I replace the source command in my autocmd?

Changed ts=2 to sts=2, thanks for the heads-up!  I don't see any ts= or sts= settings in the yaml.vim files listed above.

Comment: BTW according to `vim -V` it was sourcing yaml.vim all along.  It still is now; I see it in the `vim -V` output.  Also `autocommand setf yaml`, `autocommand setlocal ai sts=2` etc.

Comment: I tried replacing my ~/.vim/yaml.vim file with all 3 of the options under /usr/share/vim (one at a time).  Still no syntax highlighting.  But at least I have proper tabs, tab expansion, etc.

Comment: Aha!  Looks like I needed `syntax on`.  With `syntax on` and `filetype on` in my .vimrc, it's working properly for both root and non-root, huzzah!  (Don't ask me why I didn't need them before....)    

I'm still using my own yaml.vim file.  How should I get it to use the authoritative copy under /usr/share/vim?    

Thanks for your help all, esp. @filbranden.  Would you like to add an actual answer so I can upvote it & mark it as the answer?

Comment: Ah -- I can just REMOVE the `source ~/.vim/yaml.vim` from .vimrc and then it pulls it from /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/yaml.vim.  So I think I'm good now!  
(Sorry about all the comments, can't edit after 5 minutes...)

Comment: Aaaand... now that everything is working properly, I **DON'T** need the `filetype on`.  I deleted it and it still works.  I **DO** need the `syntax on`.

Comment: Use `sudoedit` to edit files owned by root.